# Making my search box vulnerable to XSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

I been working on this simple search box to search a name in a table, that one I have a success of, now i been looking into a lot of stuff on how to make this search box vulnerable (which is a course requirement that im doing).

Where when I input `<script>alert("boom!");</script>` will alert on my page but in my current code it dont really do that which i dont know why as well is it because im using jquery?

I would appreciate if someone would take a look at my code and make this piece vulnerable :)

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#search').on('click', function(){
    var term = $('#term').val().toLowerCase();

    $.each(list,function(index,value){
      var count = arrayInArray(term,list[index]);
      console.log(count);
      $("tr:eq(" + (count + 1) + ") td").each(function(){
        var tb = [];
        tb.push($(this).text());
        console.log(tb); // data to be printed somewhere
      });
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <input id="term" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Participant...">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="search" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Executing client-side code on your own computer isn't a very interesting vulnerability. I could open the developer tools of my browser and type `alert(boom)` in its JS console to the same effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking why, if you enter script into the search box, that script *isn't* executed, it's because of this line:

```
var term = $('#term').val().toLowerCase();
```

This line is extracting the **string** contents of the search box (that's what JQuery's **[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** does and it works the same as the standard DOM **[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** property). So, to JavaScript, it isn't executable code, it's just a string with any markup characters in it escaped.

If you were to use the contents of the search box in a way that allows the HTML content within it to execute, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#search').on('click', function(){
    var term = $('#term').val().toLowerCase(); 
    
    // Note that the console will show the actual script element!
    console.log(term);
    
    // But here, you are taking that string and asking
    // for it to be parsed as HTML, so the escaped characters
    // are are parsed as HTML.
    $(".input-group-btn").html(term); // <-  XSS vulnerabe!

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <input id="term" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Participant..." 
         value="<script>alert('Boom!');</script>">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="search" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

You'd be vulnerable because the user's input would be processed as HTML and if you entered: `<script>...</script>` the script would be executed. JQuery's **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** method, which, from their documentation states:

> By design, any jQuery constructor or method that accepts an HTML
>   string — jQuery(), .append(), .after(), etc. — can potentially execute
>   code. This can occur by injection of script tags or use of HTML
>   attributes that execute code (for example, `<img onload="">`). Do not
>   use these methods to insert strings obtained from untrusted sources
>   such as URL query parameters, cookies, or form inputs. Doing so can
>   introduce **cross-site-scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities**. Remove or escape
>   any user input before adding content to the document.

`.html()` correlates to the DOM standard **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** property, however `.innerHTML` is safer, as the documentation states:

> HTML5 specifies that a `<script>` tag inserted via
>   innerHTML should not execute.

Also, if you used the much dreaded `eval()` function (which is about the worst thing you could do - but, hey, you asked for it), you'd be vulnerable as well:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#search').on('click', function(){
    var term = $('#term').val().toLowerCase();
  
    // eval() takes a string and evaluates it as JavaScript
    // No <script> tag needed!
    eval(term); // <-- XSS vulnerability here!
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <input id="term" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Participant..." value="alert('Boom!');">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="search" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

The documentation for **[`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)** states:

> ### Don't use eval needlessly!
>
> eval() is a dangerous function, which
>   executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller. If
>   you run eval() with a string that could be affected by a malicious
>   party, you may end up running malicious code on the user's machine
>   with the permissions of your webpage / extension. More importantly,
>   third party code can see the scope in which eval() was invoked, which
>   can lead to possible attacks in ways to which the similar Function is
>   not susceptible.

---

Essentially, XSS is something you become vulnerable to whenever your pages uses input that is not under control of the code in the page. User input is generally #1 on that list and is why you NEVER want to process user input as anything other than a string unless you "scrub" it for malicious content first.

Here's **[a good resource](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)** for learning about XSS and how to protect against it.

Comment: thanks for a very thorough explanation of it as well and yep this is what i want.

Answer (score 1):

I added this line `$('.input-group').html(term);` to your code. Now it is vulnerable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var list = [];

  $("td a").each(function() {
    list.push($(this).text().toLowerCase().split(" "));
  });

  $('#search').on('click', function() {
    var term = $('#term').val().toLowerCase();
    $('.input-group').html(term);

    $.each(list, function(index, value) {
      var count = arrayInArray(term, list[index]);
      console.log(count);
      $("tr:eq(" + (count + 1) + ") td").each(function() {
        var tb = [];
        tb.push($(this).text());
        console.log(tb); // data to be printed somewhere
      });
    });

  });

  function arrayInArray(needle, haystack) {
    var i = 0,
      len = haystack.length,
      target = JSON.stringify(needle);
    for (; i < len; i++) {
      if (JSON.stringify(haystack[i]) == target) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <input id="term" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Participant...">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="search" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
  </span>
</div>
```